# I'd like to generate a list based on selections made by students

Tags: microsoft-excel, list

I have several students who have selected what classes they want to be in on the first sheet. On the second sheet, I would like to generate a list for each class with the names of the students in that class based on their selections. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: With scripting yes, with Excel formulas, I don't believe so.

Comment: It can be done with formulas, but not as easily or cleanly as VBA (not that VBA would be trivial).  It might even be possible with a pivot table.  Super User isn't a free "write me code" service, so just posting a requirement is considered out of scope.  However, if you tackle this yourself and run into a specific problem, people here will help you solve that problem if you post your work and describe the issue.

Comment: @thepip3r it can be done with formulas

Comment: @fixer1234 Totally agree that the formulas are not clean!

Answer (score 2):

## 1)  Generate a header row of course names

First things first, in sheet2 you need to generate a horizontal list of classes.  You can either do this manually, or you can use the following formula to generate a sorted list of used unique class names from the students choices for class 1-3.  It should even work at ignoring blank class entries.  The only two caveats that I can think of is that you need to have the cell to the left of the list that is equal to any of the names in the list.  The other caveat is that this is an array formula and will require <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when confirming the formula.  You will know you have done it right when { } appear around the formula.  Note the { } may not be added manually.

In The example, I pasted the following formula to Sheet2!B2 and copied to the right until blank cells appeared.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9,SMALL(IF(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9)+ISBLANK(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9)=0,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9,"<"&Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9)+1,""),1)=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9),"",COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9,"<"&Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9)+1),ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9))+1),1),MATCH(MIN(IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9)+ISBLANK(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9)>0,"",COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9,"<"&Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9)+1)),INDEX(IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9),"",COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9,"<"&Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9)+1),SMALL(IF(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9)+ISBLANK(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9)=0,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9,"<"&Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9)+1,""),1)=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9),"",COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9,"<"&Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9)+1),ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9))+1),1),,1),0),1),"")
```

Being an array formula, do not use full row/column reference like A:A or 3:3 as it will cause an excessive amount of calculations to be performed.

## 2)  Generate a list of names

In order to generate a column of names that chose the course in the header row as one of their 3 choices the following formula can be used.  In the example below, this formula was places in Sheet2!B3 and copied to the right to match the list of course names and down until until there are only blank rows.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9)/(Sheet1!$B$2:$D$9=B$2),ROW(A1))),"")
```

The AGGREGATE function can perform array like operations depending on the formula number selected.  When the first parameter number is 14 or 15 and a few other apparently, array like operations will be performed.  The second number parameter tells AGGREGATE to ignore error results, hidden rows among some other things I believe.  As a result of the array like calculations, again avoid using full column references within the AGGREGATE function.

Source: Sheet1

[image]

Output:  Sheet2

[image]

IF a student chooses the same course more than once, their name will appear more than once in the list.

Comment: You proved me wrong.  It **was** trivial.  :-)  +1

Comment: Looks horrendous, not trivial.  ;)

Comment: God forbid you misplace a comma or a bracket!  Though I did learn I inconsistently spell Biology.